# Insert with Subquery and Unique Value

Tags: mysql

I want to insert into a table using a select statement as well as a unique value. The following query returns an error that the column counts are not matching. What am I missing?

```
insert into moving_average (ma_symbol, ma_date, ma5)
values 
 (
      select 'A', max(temp.histDate), avg(temp.histClose)
      from
         (
          select hd.histDate, hd.histClose
          from historical_data hd
          where symbol like 'A' order by hd.histDate asc limit 5
         ) temp
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
insert into moving_average (ma_symbol, ma_date, ma5)
select 'A', max(histDate), avg(histClose)
from (select (histDate), (histClose)
      from historical_data
      where symbol like 'A'
      order by histDate asc
      limit 5) temp;
```

`INSERT INTO ... SELECT` statement does not use `VALUES` keyword.

Comment: This comes up with and error: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select 'A', max(histDate), avg(histClose)      from         (select (histDate), ' at line 3

Comment: @HenryDavidThe3rdest Check the edit I made, should work now.